# Decision in regard to adding a new project independent of the application's layers

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I m in the process of refactoring an application for witch I was tasked to restructure the app because of the bad coding and architectural design. Fortunately it is not that much work to be done because the project was started a few months ago.

After some discussions with my colleagues I have decided to separate the application into three Layers (DataAcces , Business Logic and GUI).

I have restructured the entire solution putting into the mix Entity Framework , Automapper and Unity.

After I had a discussion with my Project Manager I learned that at some point it may be required to replace Entity Framework and Unity with NHibernate and Ninject , because of the client's team knowledge with these frameworks.

It will take some time before this decision is taken and it may be possible that someone else will have to do this.

I have decided to create wrappers around around Entity Framework , Automapper and Unity and place them in a separate project , if at some point in the application lifetime the decision will be taken to change them.

As it stands I am not sure to witch layer in my application will this project belong because it contains code that is needed by all layers.For example:

-Entity Framework - DatAccess

-Automapper - Service Layer

-Unity - GUI Layer, Service Layer , DataAcces Layer

Because of this a reference will exist to this project in all  layers of my application.

I am not sure if this will be good for the overall architecture of the application.
What I know so far regarding N-tier architectures is that you have to have clear separations between your layers.

Is there a better option for this that I am missing , or it is correct to proceed this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a DataContracts project.

So the references will be like this:

- DataAcces Layer

  - Entity Framework - note: this should not be exposed for public, the DAL should wrap it
  - DataContracts
- Automapper

  - DataContracts
- GUI Layer

  - DataContracts
- Service Layer

  - DataContracts
- Unity

  - DataAcces Layer
  - Automapper
  - DataContracts
  - GUI Layer
  - Service Layer

Your layers should have interfaces that are defined in the DataContracts project. For example, in your Service Layer you won't depend on a DataAccesController, you'll depend on an IDataAccesController. You can use the unity layer to wire everything together, since that's what unity is for.

Having an interchangeable IoC framework is not really recommended.

If the client decides they rather have nhibernate instead of entity framework, they'd only have to modify the DAL

of course I have no idea about your current implementation, but this is how I'd generally set it up.